# Function with jQuery and Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a blackjack game but the code isn't quite working.  
Here is a code sample:

```
var puntuacionjugador = 0;  
$("button#newcard").click(function(){
    if (i <= 4){
        possibleplayercards[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*49+1);
        $("<span id='ncarta"+i+"'>"+ valorcarta(possibleplayercards[i]) +"</span><br>").appendTo("#newplayercards div");
        console.log("ncarta"+i+"con el valor de "+valorcarta(possibleplayercards[i]));
        puntuacionjugador = puntuacionjugador + possibleplayercards[i];
        console.log(puntuacionjugador);
        i ++;
    }   
});
function puntosplayer(){
    return (valorcarta(playercard) + valorcarta(playercard2) + valorcarta(puntuacionjugador));
}
```

The code above is executed when the player requests an additional card. 
I am getting an error at:

```
puntuacionjugador = puntuacionjugador + possibleplayercards[i];
```

After this line is executed, the js console shows the number I want, but when the function puntosplayer() does the operation it doesn't work and it's 10 every time.

How can I correct this?

Comment: @adeneo `i++` and `i ++` do the same thing. A space there doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Maybe possibleplayercards[i] is not defined. Also, for something like a = a +b , use a += b instead.

Comment: can you share more context to the problem... possible create a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8BeKp/1/

Comment: where is `i` defined?

Comment: And the `puntosplayer` function is called when exactly ?